# Why does VS2019 Pro have compile errors with xutility, xmemory, and atomic when creating a CUDA project via CMake?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, cuda

I'm trying to create a simple CUDA project via CMake and getting strange compilation errors. I'm following [this tutorial](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/building-cuda-applications-cmake/).
Originally, I was using Visual Studio 2019 Community, CMake 3.18.3, and CUDA 11.3 and everything worked fine. Then, I updated to Visual Studio 2019 Professional and CMake 3.20.3, and it failed to compile the same exact same source code.

Here's my entire CMakeLists file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18.3)

project(hello_world LANGUAGES CXX CUDA)

add_executable(hello_world_target main.cu)

target_compile_features(hello_world_target PUBLIC cxx_std_11)
set_target_properties(hello_world_target PROPERTIES CUDA_SEPARABLE_COMPILATION ON)
set_target_properties(hello_world_target PROPERTIES CUDA_ARCHITECTURES "52")
```

Here's my only source file, main.cu:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
  std::cout << "Hello, world!" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

When I try to compile, I get the following errors:

```
1>Compiling CUDA source file ..\main.cu...
1>
1>C:\Users\[username]\Documents\hello_cmake\build>"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.3\bin\nvcc.exe" -gencode=arch=compute_52,code=\"compute_52,compute_52\" -gencode=arch=compute_52,code=\"sm_52,compute_52\" --use-local-env -ccbin "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\bin\HostX64\x64" -x cu -rdc=true   -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.3\include"     --keep-dir x64\Debug  -maxrregcount=0  --machine 64 --compile -cudart static -std=c++14 -Xcompiler="/EHsc -Zi -Ob0" -g  -D_WINDOWS -D"CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug\"" -D"CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug\"" -D_MBCS -Xcompiler "/EHsc /W1 /nologo /Od /Fdhello_world_target.dir\Debug\vc142.pdb /FS /Zi /RTC1 /MDd /GR" -o hello_world_target.dir\Debug\main.obj "C:\Users\[username]\Documents\hello_cmake\main.cu"
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include\xutility(1309): error : expected a "("
1>          detected during instantiation of "void std::_Adl_verify_range(const _Iter &, const _Sentinel &) [with _Iter=const char *, _Sentinel=const char *]"
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include\xlocale(1990): here
1>
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include\xutility(1309): error : expected a "("
1>          detected during instantiation of "void std::_Adl_verify_range(const _Iter &, const _Sentinel &) [with _Iter=__wchar_t *, _Sentinel=__wchar_t *]"
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include\xlocale(1991): here
1>
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include\xutility(1309): error : expected a "("
1>          detected during instantiation of "void std::_Adl_verify_range(const _Iter &, const _Sentinel &) [with _Iter=const __wchar_t *, _Sentinel=const __wchar_t *]"
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include\xlocale(2026): here

.....etc., etc., etc.....

31 errors detected in the compilation of "C:/Users/[username]/Documents/hello_cmake/main.cu".
1>main.cu
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\BuildCustomizations\CUDA 11.3.targets(785,9): error MSB3721: The command ""C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.3\bin\nvcc.exe" -gencode=arch=compute_52,code=\"compute_52,compute_52\" -gencode=arch=compute_52,code=\"sm_52,compute_52\" --use-local-env -ccbin "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\bin\HostX64\x64" -x cu -rdc=true   -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.3\include"     --keep-dir x64\Debug  -maxrregcount=0  --machine 64 --compile -cudart static -std=c++14 -Xcompiler="/EHsc -Zi -Ob0" -g  -D_WINDOWS -D"CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug\"" -D"CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug\"" -D_MBCS -Xcompiler "/EHsc /W1 /nologo /Od /Fdhello_world_target.dir\Debug\vc142.pdb /FS /Zi /RTC1 /MDd /GR" -o hello_world_target.dir\Debug\main.obj "C:\Users\[username]\Documents\hello_cmake\main.cu"" exited with code 1.
1>Done building project "hello_world_target.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
```

What's perplexing is that this worked fine with the different versions of Visual Studio and CMake. Also, if I rewrite the CMakeLists.txt file to remove `CUDA` from the `LANGUAGES` list, and change `main.cu` to `main.cpp`, everything works fine.

It's also confusing that the compiler would complain about the xutility, xmemory, and atomic files. That sounds like a red herring, though.

What could be causing this issue?

UPDATE 10/20/2021: For me, VS2019 16.11.5 works fine with CUDA 11.4.120 and CMake 3.21.3, no modifications needed.

Comment: You likely have a too new version of MSVC for CUDA 11.3. You might need to downgrade to something a little bit earlier. What exact compile and IDE version have you installed?

Comment: There is a suspicious lack of `/std:` being passed to the host compiler. I can't tell for sure if that's the cause though.

Comment: @talonmies I couldn't find the MSVC version, but my current IDE version is 16.10.0. I think when I was using VS2019 Community it was one of the 16.9.x versions.

Comment: @talonmies I downgraded from 16.10.0 to 16.9.6 and it works again. Seems like an issue with the latest VS2019 version.

Comment: Only 16.9.x is officially supported AFAIK

Comment: You don't need to downgrade Visual Studio. You can use the very latest VS, but use the installer to additionally install the MSVC 14.28 toolchain. Then specify that toolchain version to vcvarsall.bat to open a command-prompt with that specific toolchain/compiler version. Worked like a charm for me.

Answer (score 6):

I ran into basically the same problem after upgrading from Visual Studio 2019 16.9.6 to 16.10.
The problem seems to be caused by changes in xutility, xmemory etc. in the version of the MSVC v142 build tools 14.29.30037 delivered with Visual Studio 2019 16.10.

I could not solve the problem for the new version of the build tools, but I found a workaround. It is possible to install the v142 build tools from VS2019 16.9 with VS2019 16.10:

In VS the installer, "Visual Studio 2019->Modify->Individual components" add

- MSVC v142 - VS2019 C++ x64/x86 build tools (14.28-16.9)
- C++ v14.28 (16.9) ATL for v142 build tools (x86 & x64)
- optionally: MFC, commandline tools, etc.

To compile the CUDA CMake project the MSVC toolset version needs to be set explicitly. This can be done by entering

```
version=14.28.29910
```

in "Optional toolset to use (argument to -T) in the CMake GUI (CMake cache needs to be deleted).

Comment: Were you able to fix it?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/29076586)

Comment: Sorry @EJoshuaS-ReinstateMonica but this absolutely and completely answers the question, and is in fact the correct and best solution. It goes to the heart of the problem that the 14.29 toolchain is the problem, and the solution is to install the 14.28 toolchain. On top of that, this answer provides the right guidance on how to then tell CMake to use that specific toolchain version. I feel like 1) the reviews are very harsh towards a newcomer and 2) you seem to not be familiar enough with this specific area/problem to appreciate the quality of this answer.

Comment: I appreciate this is a very narrow and specific area, but I really cannot fathom how all four reviewers recommended this answer for deletion...
Thank you for this great answer @AlexB - and the fact that this got other upvotes speaks for itself too.

Comment: @Ela782 You should have a quick look at the edit history before going on such a stampede. At the time of reviewing this answer was *"I ran into basically the same problem after upgrading from Visual Studio 2019 16.9.6 to 16.10."* I hope that you agree that this is indeed NOT an answer...

Comment: @Tomerikoo Oh, gotcha! Well, I completely agree then of course! Let me rephrase then: The original answer was indeed worthy of improvement and of somewhat low quality (it still got to the heart of the problem though!) - and I think we both agree then that the current answer is great :) Thank you for pointing me to the history, and sorry then!

Comment: @Ela782 The original answer wasn't an answer (and should have been a comment at best). The edited version is, indeed, an excellent answer.

Answer (score 4):

Nothing wrong with the program and with the MSVC compiler and libs. You can use the latest release (now 16.10.1)
cmake generated this (chaotic) compiler command in the vs 2019 IDE:
"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.3\bin\nvcc.exe" -gencode=arch=compute_75,code="compute_75,compute_75" -gencode=arch=compute_75,code="sm_75,compute_75" --use-local-env -ccbin "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\bin\HostX64\x64" -x cu -rdc=true   -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.3\include"     --keep-dir x64\Release  -maxrregcount=0  --machine 64 --compile -cudart static -std=c++14 -Xcompiler="/EHsc -Ob2"   -D_WINDOWS -DNDEBUG -D"CMAKE_INTDIR="Release"" -D_MBCS -D"CMAKE_INTDIR="Release"" -Xcompiler "/EHsc /W1 /nologo /O2 /Fdhello_world_target.dir\Release\vc142.pdb /FS   /MD /GR" -o hello_world_target.dir\Release\main.obj "D:\projects\test\main.cu"

remove additional option: -std=c++14 in this command and it works

Why:
With cuda 11.3 and MSVC 19.29.++ MSVC arranges itself the setting for the host compiler icw NVCC, so using this option gives problems.
It must be edited in the CMAKE release. Module compiler(NVIDIA-CUDA.cmake) I think. I'm not an expert on that, but you can see there a lot of hocus-pocus around this option.

Also Windows Visual Studio does not support specifying CUDAHOSTCXX or CMAKE_CUDA_HOST_COMPILER env settings and gives problems like this.
I used cmake version 3.20.3 and win-build 3.20.20210609-g5e26887 to test.