# How can I change MSVC compiler version in a CMAKE project?

Tags: c++, cmake, clion, msvc12

Since microsoft broke the compiler (again) in version `14.29.30037` (reported as `19.29.30038.1` by CMAKE for some reason) ([look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67732065/why-does-vs2019-pro-have-compile-errors-with-xutility-xmemory-and-atomic-when)) I need to go back to `14.28.something`. I already downloaded `14.28.29910` through Visual Studio Installer and my `Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC` folder now contains folders with both versions.

However I can't find a way to force CMAKE to use this particular older version. I use CLion CMAKE integration and my settings look like this. [image: toolchain settings][image: cmake settings]

Please note that I've already tried setting `Make`, `C Compiler` and `C++ Compiler` paths to their counterparts in older compiler. This results in CMAKE reporting the desired 19.28.29915.0 compiler version (love the number of different versioning conventions microsoft uses by the way). Despite that, when I try to build the project I get the following:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include\yvals_core.h(541): fatal error C1189: #error:  STL1001: Unexpected compiler version, expected MSVC 19.29 or newer.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~2\2019\COMMUN~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1428~1.299\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
```

I guess this implies that not all parts of the compiler (some includes in this case) were switched to the old version.

If for some reason any piece of my code would help you with answering this question, the repo is available [here](https://github.com/qazedcwsx4/heat)

Please also note that despite how much I'd love to simply switch to GCC, I cannot because of CUDA support on Windows. I also cannot use different (older) Visual Studio version as the project requires C++ 20. Also, bonus question: How is it possible for a company as relevant as microsoft to literally break an enterprise-class development tool?

Comment: Did you try 'Tools->CMake->Reset Cache and Reload Project' in CLion?

Answer (score 1):

The following solution helped me:

1. Find `vcvarsall.bat` in the directory with your Visual Studio installation. (I have `Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat`)
2. Run `vcvarsall.bat <your_arch> -vcvars_ver=<msvc_version>`. In your case, put `-vcvars_ver=14.28`. Example of `<your_arch>` is `amd64`. This will set all the environment variables for desired MSVC version.
3. Start CLion from the command line with the created environment.